# Вопрос по SQL, Java и времени

Tags: java, sql, дата

По коду

```
Date date = new Date();
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

получается формат времени 2017-11-30 19:09:24
Как сделать так, чтобы добавлялась только дата без времени и желатьельно, чтобы было ДД-ММ-ГГ?

Comment: Два встречных вопроса: при чём SQL и обязательно ли использовать устаревший `Date`?

Comment: Есть колонка в SQL типа Timestamp, хочу чтобы дата в мою таблицу заносилась автоматически поэтому и использую данную конструкцию

Comment: Как работаете с базой? JDBC? JPA?

Comment: Работаю с JDBC.

Comment: надо просто обнулить время, лучше всего это делает sql

Answer (score 0):

Если поле в базе объявлено, как `date`

```
String query = "INSERT INTO news (publication_date) VALUES (?)";
try (PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
    st.setObject(1, LocalDate.now());
    st.executeUpdate();
}
```